# Pulling a substring for each line in file

Tags: powershell, foreach, substring

Using Powershell, I am simply trying to pull 15 characters starting from the 37th position of any record that begins with a 6.  I'd like to loop through and generate a record for each instance so it can later be put into an output file.  But I seem to not be hitting the correct syntax just to return the 15 characters  I know I am missing something obvious.  Been at this for a while.  Here is my script:

```
$content = Get-Content -Path .\tmfhsyst*.txt | Where-Object { $_.StartsWith("6") }

foreach ($line in $contents) 
{
  $val102 = $line.substring(36,15)
}

write-output $val102
```

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong? Are you getting any error messages or seeing incorrect results?

Comment: Shouldn't your `write-output` be inside of the `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 0):

Just as Bill_Stewart pointed out, you need to move your `Write-Output` line inside the ForEach loop. A possibly better way to do it would just be to pipe it:

```
Get-Content -Path .\tmfhsyst*.txt | Where-Object { $_.StartsWith("6") } | foreach{$_.substring(36,15)}
```

That should give you the output you desired.

Comment: Thank you very much! That created the substring in an array. It worked well. Now I need to create a variable for each of the returned values. The variable being $val102. This is just one of several variables that are substrings of $line. So, $val013 could be substring(5,4), for example. Ultimately the output would look something like: 

    write-output "102,$val102"
    write-output "103,$val103"

Answer (score 0):

Using `Substring()` has the disadvantage that it will raise an error if the string is shorter than start index + substring length. You can avoid this with a regular expression match:

```psh
(Get-Content -Path .\tmfhsyst*.txt) -match '^6.{35}(.{15})' | % { $matches[1] }
```